# testing conditional rendering that relies on state using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

What would be the way to test a component that relies on the initial state for conditional rendering ?

For example `showLessFlag` is dependent on state, and testing state in react-testing-library is counter productive.

so how would i test this condition in the `CommentList` component

```
{showLessFlag === true ? (
    // will show most recent comments below
    showMoreComments()
) : (
    <Fragment>
        {/* filter based on first comment, this shows by default */}
        {filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="comment">
                <CommentListContainer ref={ref} comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
            </div>
        ))}
    </Fragment>
)}
```

Should it be test like the following

```
  it("should check more comments", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        const commentList = getByTestId("comment-show-more");
        expect(commentList).toBeNull();
    });
```

But im getting this error because of the conditional rendering

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by:
>   [data-testid="comment-show-more"]

**CommentList.tsx**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, Ref } from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import OurSecondaryButton from "../../../common/OurSecondaryButton";
import CommentListContainer from "../commentListContainer/commentListContainer";

function CommentList(props: any, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>) {
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<Number>(2);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const [showLessFlag, setShowLessFlag] = useState<Boolean>(false);
    const the_comments = props.comments.length;
    const inc = showMore as any;
    const min = Math.min(2, the_comments - inc);
    const showComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (inc + 2 && inc <= the_comments) {
            setShowMore(inc + 2);
            setShowLessFlag(true);
        } else {
            setShowMore(the_comments);
        }
    };
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpenModal(true);
    };
    const handleCloseModal = () => {
        setOpenModal(false);
    };

    const showLessComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowMore(2);
        setShowLessFlag(false);
    };
    const isBold = (comment) => {
        return comment.userId === props.userId ? 800 : 400;
    };
    // show comments by recent, and have the latest comment at the bottom, with the previous one just before it.
    const filterComments = props.comments
        .slice(0)
        .sort((a, b) => {
            const date1 = new Date(a.createdAt) as any;
            const date2 = new Date(b.createdAt) as any;
            return date2 - date1;
        })
        .slice(0, inc)
        .reverse();

    const showMoreComments = () => {
        return filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
            <div data-testid="comment-show-more" key={i} className="comment">
                <CommentListContainer ref={ref} comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
            </div>
        ));
    };

    return (
        <Grid data-testid="comment-list-div">
            <Fragment>
                <div style={{ margin: "30px 0px" }}>
                    {props.comments.length > 2 ? (
                        <Fragment>
                            {min !== -1 && min !== -2 ? (
                                <Fragment>
                                    {min !== 0 ? (
                                        <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                            View {min !== -1 && min !== -2 ? min : 0} More Comments
                                        </OurSecondaryButton>
                                    ) : (
                                        <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showLessComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                            Show Less Comments
                                        </OurSecondaryButton>
                                    )}
                                </Fragment>
                            ) : (
                                <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showLessComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                    Show Less Comments
                                </OurSecondaryButton>
                            )}
                        </Fragment>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </Fragment>
            {showLessFlag === true ? (
                // will show most recent comments below
                showMoreComments()
            ) : (
                <Fragment>
                    {/* filter based on first comment  */}
                    {filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
                        <div key={i} className="comment">
                            <CommentListContainer ref={ref} comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </Fragment>
            )}
        </Grid>
    );
}

export default React.forwardRef(CommentList) as React.RefForwardingComponent<HTMLDivElement, any>;
```

**CommentList.test.tsx**

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import React, { Ref } from "react";
import CommentList from "./CommentList";
import { render, getByText, queryByText, getAllByTestId } from "@testing-library/react";

const props = {
    user: {},
    postId: null,
    userId: null,
    currentUser: {},
    ref: {
        current: undefined,
    },
    comments: [
        {
            author: { username: "barnowl", gravatar: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png", bio: null },
            comment_body: "fsfsfsfsfs",
            createdAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            gifUrl: "",
            id: 520,
            postId: 28,
            updatedAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            userId: 9,
        },
        {
            author: { username: "barnowl", gravatar: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png", bio: null },
            comment_body: "fsfsfsfsfs",
            createdAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            gifUrl: "",
            id: 519,
            postId: 27,
            updatedAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            userId: 10,
        },
    ],
    deleteComment: jest.fn(),
};
describe("Should render <CommentList/>", () => {
    it("should render <CommentList/>", () => {
        const commentList = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        expect(commentList).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should render first comment", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        const commentList = getByTestId("comment-list-div");
        expect(commentList.firstChild).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should render second child", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        const commentList = getByTestId("comment-list-div");
        expect(commentList.lastChild).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should check comments", () => {
        const rtl = render(<CommentList {...props} />);

        expect(rtl.getByTestId("comment-list-div")).toBeTruthy();
        expect(rtl.getByTestId("comment-list-div")).toBeTruthy();

        expect(rtl.getByTestId("comment-list-div").querySelectorAll(".comment").length).toEqual(2);
    });
    it("should match snapshot", () => {
        const rtl = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        expect(rtl).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it("should check more comments", () => {
      const { getByTestId } = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
      const commentList = getByTestId("comment-show-more");
      expect(commentList).toBeNull();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the codesandbox reproduction example? That's will be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any `getBy*` query in react-testing-library will throw an error if no match is found. If you want to test/assert the absence of an element then you want to use any of the `queryBy*` queries, they return null if no match is found.

[Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet#queries)

[image]

```
it("should check more comments", () => {
  const { queryByTestId } = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
  const commentList = queryByTestId("comment-show-more");
  expect(commentList).toBeNull();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this got the test passing. Appreciate it, will read more on react-testing-library use cases for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

To better answer this question, being that i have more experience with using react testing library now.

When we go about testing for conditions, we need to trigger the action that makes the change to the state.

For example in this situation

We have a condition like `showLessFlag`

```
{showLessFlag === true ? (
    // will show most recent comments below
    showMoreComments()
) : (
    <Fragment>
        {/* filter based on first comment, this shows by default */}
        {filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="comment">
                <CommentListContainer ref={ref} comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
            </div>
        ))}
    </Fragment>
)}
```

In order to properly test this, we need to trigger the event that will change `showLessFlag` to false.

So we can do something like

```
 <OurSecondaryButton
      onClick={(e) => showLessComments(e)}
      data-testid="_test-show-less"
      component="span"
      color="secondary"
    >
      Show Less Comments
 </OurSecondaryButton>
```

test

```
it("should trigger showLessComments ", () => {
   const { getByTestId } = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
   const showLessButton = getByTestId("__test-show-less");
   fireEvent.click(showLessButton);
   expect(...) // whatever to be called, check for the existence of a div tag, or whatever you want
});
```

Testing for conditions improves code coverage :)